# if statement webpage based on windows authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core

I'm very new to .NET Core and C# programming

i have used the scaffolded database structure for Index/add/edit/delete Views.

i'm trying to authenticate a user based on windows authentication which I know is working as when different users open the page the user name changes. (It's intranet only)

i would like to show and hide the edit, details and delete sections based on a user login.

```
@if (User.Identity.Name == "ManEng")
{
    <a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.TrolleyId">Edit</a>
    <a asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="@item.TrolleyId">Details</a>
    <a asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@item.TrolleyId">Delete</a>
}
else { 
    <a asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="@item.TrolleyId">Details</a>
}
```

but that obviously doesn't work. It just always uses the else.

does anyone else have and Ideas?

I didn't want to create a table of users which most of the solutions i found relied on I would like something fairly simple :). Thanks

Comment: Why "obviously doesn't work"? What does `User.Identity.Name` show?

Comment: When I use User.Identity.Name in the website it displays the correct username "ManEng".

Answer (score 0):

The if on `User.Identity.Name == "username"` is only going to work for a user who happens to be called "username". The `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` property is what you need here for all authenticated users.

```
@if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
    <a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.TrolleyId">Edit</a>
    <a asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="@item.TrolleyId">Details</a>
    <a asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@item.TrolleyId">Delete</a>                
}
else 
{ 
    <a asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="@item.TrolleyId">Details</a>
}
```

EDIT: For that specific user, you could user `User.Identity.Name == "ManEng"`

Comment: Sorry username was supposed to be generic. The User is ManEng so i would like only the user ManEng to have access to edit. If that makes sense.

User.Identity.IsAuthenticated if I use this wont that give access to everyone?

Answer (score 0):

when you use User.Identity.Name i had to put the domain in first but that domain had to have \ instead of just \ which I had.

Thanks for your answers.